# List view cards doesn't work after adding if condition inside in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, flutter-listview

My list view card does not returning all the items stored by a specific user, I want to get all the products saved by the user

```
 body: (products != null)
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: products.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (products[index].ownerId == user.uid) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset('graphics/broccoli.png'),
                    title: Text(products[index].name),
                    subtitle:
                        Text(products[index].price.toString() + " Rs"),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            })
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
```

Comment: Can you provide the `products` function's code in the question?

Answer (score 3):

In the `else` part, return a `SizedBox()` instead of `null`.

```
} else {
  return const SizedBox();
}
```

This is because the build method or builder function of any widget must always return a `Widget`, and a `null` is not a `Widget`.

So whenever we want to show "nothing" or an "empty widget", we can simply return a `SizedBox()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since, [Jigar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63202237/5362583) was apt, I would like to give you some dart precise way to do this.

- You can return `Container()` too, it is basically used to show for empty container.
- Rather than doing the return with a check, you can follow your first technique only, that is, using `ternary operator` for returning `Card` or `Container`

You can do it like this:

```
               return (products[index].ownerId == user.uid) ? Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset('graphics/broccoli.png'),
                    title: Text(products[index].name),
                    subtitle:
                        Text(products[index].price.toString() + " Rs"),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert)
                  )
                ) : Container();
```

Comment: Size box is always a better option, has it specifically designed with height & width, Container has lot of other params.

Comment: Yep @jitsm555 I agree, but declaring just a `Container()` will work just fine like `SizedBox()` without `height` and `width`. Thanks for the suggestions anyways. I have been using `Container()` every time when this type of situation comes up, but would definitely give it a try